# extjs adding items to a radio button

Tags: javascript, extjs, radio-button, extjs3

I want to add items to a radio button,
 but the documentation doesn't seem to have an items config for a radio button.
Is there any way to achieve the code below?

```
var rb = new Ext.form.Radio({

 boxLabel: 'Parent',
 items: [{
   title: 'child1'
}]

});
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the RadioGroup instead? http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.form.RadioGroup

Comment: they only take radio buttons as items, not checkboxes

Comment: Your question includes a radio button - hence why I posted the RadioGroup. You could also have looked through the documentation on the same page and gone to: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.form.CheckboxGroup I think you may need to spend some more time reading the documentation.

Comment: i did, checkboxgroups(parents) can take checkboxes and radiobuttons, but what if i want a panel or any item as a child?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? A checkboxgroup is for just that - a group of checkboxes...